Error when starting spring boot admin "Couldn't retrieve status for Instance"
I'm currently trying Eureka server with Spring Boot admin with the following setup:
> Spring Boot Version: 3.2.1 
> Spring Boot Admin Version: 3.2.1 
> Eureka Server for Service Discovery

When I attempt to start Spring Boot Admin, I encounter the following error in the console:
> Couldn't retrieve status for Instance(
>  id=32f1b3fba304,
>  version=0,
>  registration=Registration(
>   name=GATEWAY,
>   managementUrl=http://host:port/actuator,
>   healthUrl=http://host:port/actuator/health,
>   serviceUrl=http://host:port,
>   source=discovery
>  ),
>  registered=true,
>  statusInfo=StatusInfo(
>   status=UNKNOWN,
>   details={}
>  ),
>  statusTimestamp=2024-05-14T10:50:43.446449Z,
>  info=Info(values={}),
>  endpoints=Endpoints(
>   endpoints={health=Endpoint(id=health, url=http://host:port/actuator/health)}
>  ),
>  buildVersion=null,
>  tags=Tags(values={})
> )

The application is configured to use Eureka for service discovery. Despite the error, the instance appears as UP in the Eureka dashboard, but Spring Boot Admin shows its status as UNKNOWN. I've confirmed that the URLs provided in the registration are accessible.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I fix it to correctly reflect the status in Spring Boot Admin?
Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

From the provided output it is not visible why the status could not be retrieved. Maybe something with the host/port not being correct/resolvable/reachable. Please have a look at the logs if there is more information.
There is a complete example including all infrastructure etc for eureka available here:
https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin-runtime-playground/tree/main/eureka
